# How to edit filters list of a queryset

Tags: python, django

This feature is used in a view where I list search results. In my search form, I have some ModelChoiceFields to search by foreign keys. Usual workflow mean turn our current search more and more precise, so to disable a lot of not pertinent results, I'm trying to remove entries which would return no result if no other search parameters change.

I'm using an object queryset to restrict propositions in some dropdown lists.
I use theses dropdown lists to filter by foreign keys my objects list.

My function argument to filter is an Objects queryset, for now :

```
class MySearchForm(Form):
    things = ModelChoiceField(queryset=models.Thing.objects.none())
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        my_objects_queryset = kwargs.pop('my_objects_queryset',models.Thing.objects.all())
        super(MySearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['things'].queryset = \
            models.Thing.objects.filter(object__in=my_objects_queryset).distinct()
```

My problem is how to remove a 'where close' from an existing query_set.
Here, I want to remove from my_objects_queryset where closes which filter by `thing = ForeignKey(models.Thing)`

Is it possible?

Something like a way to list all the filters of our queryset and edit/delete them on the fly.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are trying to do, but maybe you are looking for `exclude` which is opposite of `filter`? [Link to docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#exclude)

Comment: I have a queryset with many filters and I want to list them and remove some of them before getting objects. An exclude method can't 'disable' a filter made on a queryset (I'm french, maybe I'm not clear)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Short answer:

No, you *cannot* do that.

#### Long answer:

Theoretically, it may be possible (to some extent anyway) but *certainly not advisable*.

*(I have not fully studied the django source, so what follows is a result of a simple climb up the call tree.)*

Looking at the [source for QuerySet](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/query.py?rev=15491#L559), `filter()` and `exclude()` return a clone of the queryset itself with the new rule added on (using `clone.query.add_q()`).

`clone.query` is an [object representing an SQL Query](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/sql/query.py?rev=15491#L90) while the [add_q()](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/sql/query.py?rev=15491#L1139) method adds the new rule to [`clone.query.where`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/sql/where.py?rev=15491#L23) which is essentially a root node of a [tree](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/utils/tree.py?rev=15491#L8).

How the new node is added to the tree depends on whether the rule is to be connected with an `AND` or an `OR` clause. This is important as it affects the correctness of the final SQL query that is [generated](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/sql/where.py?rev=15491#L75).

So, to list filters assigned to a queryset, one *"simply"* need to understand how the `queryset.query.where` tree is represented (see [`django.utils.tree`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/utils/tree.py?rev=15491)).

The difficult bit is of course the removing filters such that it does not affect the remaining rules. I shall refrain from offering a solution as there is no guarantee that the implementation will not change thus invalidating the solution. I suspect it is possible to do but it smells of something that should only be done out of academic interest, or not at all.

Comment: Great well documented reply, thanx a lot. It sounds pretty clear now.

Comment: "but certainly not advisable" I agree :)

Answer (score 8):

Some hacking here.

You can bypass it by "reseting" the current filters as below:

```
from django.db.models.sql.where import WhereNode

qs = YourModel.objects.filter(column=1).all()
qs.query.where = WhereNode() # resets current filters
qs.all() # now you can apply new filters
```